# Cisco Compatible vpn (vpnc) ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I installed Cisco Compatible vpn using following commnand:

```
sudo apt install vpnc network-manager-vpnc network-manager-vpnc-gnome
```

I have set my credentials and tried to connect, but I can only reach a few sites available from the vpn. If I try connecting using Cisco vpn client on windows, the websites work.

Can you help me figure out what the problem is? How can I troubleshoot this?

Windows IP Configuration

```
Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP-PCM1MKP
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (DockerNAT):

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-DE-E9-00
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::60c2:d3ee:63ce:7279%23(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.75.1(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 98-3B-8F-77-20-5F
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 9A-3B-8F-77-20-5E
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Cisco Systems VPN Adapter for 64-bit Windows
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-05-9A-3C-78-00
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c400:bb69:cdab:6249%16(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.2.192(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.17.0.1
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 738198938
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-24-15-96-AB-9C-EB-E8-39-2E-14
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 62.217.251.212
62.217.251.199
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 98-3B-8F-77-20-5E
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a02:2f04:131:7700:e559:5591:1190:f544(Preferred)
Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2a02:2f04:131:7700:58b3:3010:83a1:2de9(Preferred)
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e559:5591:1190:f544%5(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.19(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, May 28, 2019 3:52:39 PM
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, May 31, 2019 3:53:32 PM
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1%5
192.168.100.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.100.1
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 77085583
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-24-15-96-AB-9C-EB-E8-39-2E-14
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1%5
192.168.100.1
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-15-5D-9E-C2-29
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a1b0:ce:329:fce2%29(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.168.129(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 486544733
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-24-15-96-AB-9C-EB-E8-39-2E-14
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Output ifconfig output:

```
tun0:

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         tun0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           tun
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            1412
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     tun0
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/10
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.17.2.198/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            0.0.0.0
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 50
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 172.17.2.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 50
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::7ceb:42f2:1066:ec61/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256

docker0:

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         docker0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bridge
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         02:42:4E:63:79:6E
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     docker0
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.17.0.1/16
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 172.17.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::42:4eff:fe63:796e/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256

wlp2s0

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         9C:B6:D0:D9:1A:E9
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wifi Home
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.104/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.0.1/32, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 62.217.213.233/32, nh = 192.168.0.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.0.1, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = 192.168.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[5]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::7493:61eb:a777:afde/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600

veth9b0ca8a

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         veth9b0ca8a
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         D2:C4:A5:AC:C3:17
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show us the Connection Information from after you connect to the Cisco VPN, and compare that to `ipconfig/all` on the Windows side.

Comment: One way to show what I asked for is to run `ifconfig`, and then `nmcli dev show XXXX` for each network device except `lo`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added output from ipconfig all and nmcli output

Comment: "*Unknown adapter VPN - VPN Client:   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected*" You need to show what they look like when the Cisco VPN is running.

Comment: The logs are with vpn open, I don't know what is that Unknown adapter, but I configured another windows with cisco vpn and I updated the log. Unknown adapter doesn't apear. Do you know another vpn client that I can use?